# Unable to set CSS background-image property with JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, css, svg

Edit:

For whatever reason, this does not work with JavaScript. It won't let you set the background image multiple times. To fix this, I set the backgroundPosition property to `calc(50% + translation_x) calc(50% + translation_y)` instead of setting a transformation in the image. This seems to work (for now).

---

I am unable to set the "background-image" property of an element dynamically with JavaScript. I have had no issues doing so in the past, but my current script does not work at all. There are no error messages in the console, so I haven't the slightest idea what's happening.

I have created vector graphics for a game and I am attempting to move them across the screen using a group (`<g transform = "translate(x, y)">`). My script takes the current background of the element, `background.style.backgroundImage`, and replaces the line containing the group with the transformed version.

Now, if I run

```
background.style.backgroundImage = "url(\"" + transformed_background + "\")";
console.log(background.style.backgroundImage);
```

the old version of the background image (without transformations) is (predictably) displayed in the output and the image does not update. For instance, the output might be

```
… <svg xmlns=\'http://www.w3.org/2000/svg\' width=\'5000\' height=\'5000\'><g> …
```

while the output of

```
console.log(transformed_background);
```

is correct, and is something to the effect of

```
… <svg xmlns=\"http://www.w3.org/2000/svg\" width=\"5000\" height=\"5000\"><g transform="translate(1327.0717423133253, 1819.0229885057504)"> …
```

The background of the element will not change, despite my best efforts. I have tried everything imaginable in an attempt to resolve this issue. I believed it might be caused by the loop it is in (with an interval of about 50 ms), but increasing the interval had no effect. This system works elsewhere in the script (where the background is set initially), and this segment uses the same method.

The script is available [here](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/bBgBaV?editors=1010), and the issue is on line 175.

Any information would be much appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: Oh noes, I died

Comment: @zer00ne Unfortunately, the game is nowhere near finished, so there's no way to *not* die.

Answer (score 1):

The only thing I see is at line 177,
where you use the var from line 175.

You wrote there

```
document.getElementById("background").backgroundImage = "url(\"" + build_background + ")";
```

But if I am not wrong you change the background with js like that.

```
document.getElementById("background").style.backgroundImage = "url(\"" + build_background + ")";
```

So you forgot the style.

Btw why do you write the js in the html window and not in the window for js?

Comment: Thanks for the response! Unfortunately, adding ".style" does not fix the problem (I am sure I had this before desperately trying to fix it). Everything is in one window because the site is one page (I don't need to re-use JavaScript functions or CSS rules) so it's easier to see everything at once. I just copied the source from my computer to the site to share it in this question.